# What is wrong with this code to affix the top navigation bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

How do I affix an element? I have searched for weeks and found many tutorials and examples that all either have some java script or say to set data-spy to affix and set data-offset-top to the amount of pixels to scroll before fixing the element. I have tried it all and none of it works, the top navigation bar does not become fixed. Am I forgetting some CSS or something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#topDiv {
    width:100%;
    height:75px;
    padding:15px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:grey;
    margin-0;
}

.topNavContainer {
    height:71px;
    background-color:#8AC007;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0 !important;
    z-index:999;
}

.topNavLinks {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:71px;
    width:auto;
    margin:auto;
}

.topNavLinks a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
}

.topNavLinks a:hover {
    color:#8AC007;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;   
}

#Main {
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    width:85%;
    height:1900px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:71px;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="topDiv">
<h2>This is the Top Section</h2>
</div>

<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="75" class="topNavContainer">
<div class="topNavLinks">
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Section 3</a>
<a href="#">Section 2</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="Main">
<h1 style="color:white;">
This is the Body
</h1>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change the order of script use jquery before bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affix will add `position:fixed` to your element. So delete `position:absolute` from `.topNavcontainer` and add an affix class to your CSS with `top:0` to it.

> **Affix** affix.js
>
> **Positioning via CSS**
>
> The affix plugin toggles between three classes, each representing a particular state: .affix, .affix-top, and .affix-bottom. You must provide the styles, with the **exception of position: fixed;** on .affix, for these classes yourself (independent of this plugin) to handle the actual positions.

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) is the link to the **Affix.js** plugin documentaion.

```css
#topDiv {
  width:100%;
  height:75px;
  padding:15px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:grey;
  margin:0;
}

.topNavContainer {
  height:71px;
  background-color:#8AC007;
  width:100%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:0 !important;
  z-index:999;
}

.affix {
 top:0;
}

.topNavLinks {
  text-align:center;
  line-height:71px;
  width:auto;
  margin:auto;
}

.topNavLinks a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
}

.topNavLinks a:hover {
  color:#8AC007;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;   
}

#Main {
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
  width:85%;
  height:1900px;
  background-color:black;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:71px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="topDiv">
  <h2>This is the Top Section</h2>
</div>

<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="75" class="topNavContainer">
  <div class="topNavLinks">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Section 3</a>
    <a href="#">Section 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Main">
  <h1 style="color:white;">
    This is the Body
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the code works properly on this website when I click "Run code snippet" but when I put the code on Dreamweaver on my computer the .topNavContainer still doesn't become fixed when I scroll?

Comment: Are you sure you have added all the relevant *bootstrap (bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js)* files to your working project ?

Comment: Yes, the code I posted in the question is the exact code in Dreamweaver on my computer, I copied and pasted it.

Comment: You are loading bootstrap.js before jquery.js, switch that around. First jquery.js and then bootstrap.js. bootstrap.js is using jquery.js for it to work.

Comment: Thanks but I switched them around and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you copy my example again. I have changed it. You have had an error in your CSS, that i have copied without seeing it. Also it is better to add the affix class to your CSS and do the positioning in there.

Comment: Was the only error the margin-0 instead of margin:0;?

Comment: Yes. That was it. And i have moved the affix to a separate class.

Comment: The affix works now but why is there a gap between the body and the top navigation bar?

Comment: Check if you have `margin-top` on your `#Main` div.